# Joomla 3 user_usergroup_map table set a group_id=9 after registration

Tags: registration

When I registered in my site a name, username and email and then after that it was redirected to the page I wanted but my problem is the user_usergroup_map table set a group_id=9 after registration.

Can you tell me where this happenning and can I changed the value of 9 to 2 upon registration?

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

From the dropdown menu in the admin side of your website, go to Users -> User Manager. Then in the upper right, click "Options".

One of the first few items in the options list should be "New User Registration Group", which you can adjust to be the user group that you want new users to be added to.

Comment: thank you for the time answering but it was choose already in option list new user registration group=Registered.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution make sure your $_POST are have $_POST["groups"] = array(2); 2 is the value of Registered